# Rodrigues Formula

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, rotations, cross-product

So in my homework on rotation matrices, I stumbled upon this question: 
[image]

The question asks for  $\sin(\theta)$.
So could any of you elaborate on how to approach the question. 
Note that $J$ is the skew symmetric matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the derivation for the trace relationship mentioned above from the Rodrigues formula:

$$
R =  I  + J(\hat{\omega}) \sin\theta + (1-cos\theta) J(\hat{\omega})^{2}
$$

Say $\hat{\omega} = (\omega_{1}, \omega_{2}, \omega_{3})^{T}$ then $J(\hat{\omega})$ can be written

$$
J(\hat{\omega})
= \begin{pmatrix}
0 & -\omega_{3} & \omega_{2} \\
\omega_{3} & 0 & -\omega_{1} \\
-\omega_{2} & \omega_{1} & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
J^{2}(\hat{\omega})
=\begin{pmatrix}
-\omega_{2}^{2} - \omega_{3}^{2} & \omega_{1}\omega_{2} & \omega_{1}\omega_{3} \\
\omega_{1}\omega_{2} & -\omega_{1}^{2} - \omega_{3}^{2} & 
\omega_{2}\omega_{3} \\
\omega_{1}\omega_{3} & \omega_{2}\omega_{3} &  -\omega_{1}^{2} - \omega_{2}^{2}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

We obtain the trace of these matrices:

$$
\textrm{trace} (J(\hat{\omega}) ) = 0
$$

$$
\textrm{trace}( J^{2}(\hat{\omega})) = -2 (\omega_{1}^{2} + \omega_{2}^{2} + \omega_{3}^{2}) = -2
$$

Putting this together gives

$$
\begin{aligned}
\textrm{trace} (R) &= \textrm{trace} (I) +
\sin\theta \, \textrm{trace} (J(\hat{\omega}) )
+
(1-cos\theta) \, \textrm{trace}(J^{2}(\hat{\omega}))
\\
 &= 
3 - 2 (1 - \cos\theta) 
\\
 &= 
1 + 2\cos\theta
\end{aligned}
$$

So, in summary, if $\hat{\omega}$ is known, then $\theta$ can be calculated from the trace of $R$.

Comment: Sorry, I should have added that once $\cos\theta$ is found from the trace formula, you should test both values of $\sin\theta=\pm \sqrt{1-\cos^2\theta}$ in the formula to see which one correctly recovers the matrix $R$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This really helped!

Answer (score 1):

If one has a $3$-by-$3$ rotation matrix through an angle $\theta$, then
its trace $t$ (the sum of its diagonal entries) equal $1+2\cos\theta$.
So $\cos\theta=\frac12(t-1)$, and then $\sin\theta=\sqrt{1-\cos^2\theta}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is there any external resource clarifying the equations you just mentioned?

Comment: There's always Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix